# Bookmarking site with full text search

Tags: webapp-rec, bookmarks

In face of Delicious' planned [end of life](http://dailynewsstop.com/read-tag/yahoo-stopping-delicious/), I'm trying to find an alternative solution for storing my bookmarks. This solution should have the following features:

- free (like Delicious)
- supports bookmark tagging (like Delicious)
- supports bookmark addition through bookmarklet (like Delicious)
- provides RSS feed for me, and each of my tags (like Delicious ... or at least I think)
- works well with Opera (like Delicious)
- has an easy to use user URL  (like Delicious ... as an example, here is mine: `http://www.delicious.com/Riduidel`)
- provides easy to manipulate tags URLs (as an example, Delicious allows `http://www.delicious.com/Riduidel/bluetooth+wii` which obviously filters bookmarks for Bluetooth and Wii ones)
- provides full text search on bookmarks (not like Delicious)
- maybe snapshot of website
- maybe dead link detection/correction (using as an example [http codes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_301))

Do you know such a solution?

Comment: Delicious isn't going away any time soon - http://blogs.computerworld.com/17548/no_yahoo_isnt_killing_del_icio_us?tb

Comment: Take a look at http://fetching.io, indexes all the pages you visit, then lets you search them later.

Comment: If the closing reason is valid, where is the correct place to ask such questions? OP asked for specific web application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, after some attempts, I finaly took the self-hosted route (which was absolutly not planned at the time of the question writing) with a very good project, which is a kind of delicious self-hosted clone : [Shaarli](http://sebsauvage.net/wiki/doku.php?id=php:shaarli). As one may note by looking at the very good documentation page all the features are present, and some other are nice additions (feature list borrowed from site)

- Minimalist design (simple is beautiful)
- FAST
- Dead-simple installation: Drop the files, open the page. No database required.
- Easy to use: Single button in your browser to bookmark a page
- Save url, title, description (unlimited size). Classify links with tags (with autocomplete)
- Tag renaming, merging and deletion.
- Automatic thumbnails for various services (imgur, imageshack.us, flickr, youtube, vimeo, dailymotion…)
- Automatic conversion of URLs to clickable links in descriptions. Support for http/ftp/file/apt/magnet protocols.
- Save links as public or private
- 1-clic access to your private links/notes
- Browse links by page, filter by tag or use the full text search engine
- Permalinks (with QR-Code) for easy reference
- RSS and ATOM feeds (which can be filtered by tag or text search)
- Tag cloud
- Picture wall (which can be filtered by tag or text search)
- “Links of the day” Newspaper-like digest, browsable by day.
- “Daily” RSS feed: Get each day a digest of all new links.
- PubSubHubbub protocol support
- Easy backup (Data stored in a single file)
- Compact storage (1315 links stored in 150 kb)
- Mobile browsers support
- Also works with javascript disabled
- Can import/export Netscape bookmarks (for import/export from/to Firefox, Opera, Chrome, Delicious…)
- Brute force protected login form
- Protected against XSRF, session cookie hijacking.
- Automatic removal of annoying FeedBurner/Google FeedProxy parameters in URL (?utm_source…)
- Shaarli is a bookmarking application, but you can use it for micro-blogging (like Twitter), a pastebin, an online notepad, a snippet repository, etc.
- You will be automatically notified by a discreet popup if a new version is available
- Pages are easy to customize (using CSS and simple RainTPL templates)

Answer (score 0):

Delicious isn't going away any time soon as James L said...

... but nonetheless, there is [diigo](http://diigo.com).

It does most of the requested features and it even has an [Instruction & FAQ](http://diigo.com/transition-from-delicious-to-diigo-faq) site about the transition from Delicious to Diigo.

Answer (score 0):

[Pinboard.in](http://pinboard.in/switch/) provides most of the features you are looking for, although it isn't free. $25/year to get full text search.

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently in the process of testing [trunk.ly](http://trunk.ly), which more or less provides most of the pelasing features I mentionned upper. Obviously, there is no Opera bookmarklet yet, but a delicious synchronization tool that allow seamless bookmarking. In fact, the most missing feature seems to be the impossibility to easily combine tags in URL, which is hopefully replaced by a very powerful search engine.

Comment: trunk.ly is down now. http://trunkly.wordpress.com/2012/03/09/and-now-the-end-is-near/

Answer (score 0):

Try [Pinterest](http://www.pinterest.com/), the popular visual social bookmarking website for both pictures and video.